# remoção de dados relacionado JPA e Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Tenho duas classes, `Fornecedor` e `Produto` e quando cadastro o `Produto` e escolho um `Fornecedor` salva normal, mas na hora de remover um `Produto` ou  `Fornecedor` que esta relacionado a um `Produto` não acontece nada.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

**Classe do produto**

```
@Entity
@Table (name="Produto")
public class Produto {

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn (name="idFornecedor")
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE)
private Fornecedor fornecedor;
```

**Classe Fornecedor**

```
@Entity
@Table (name="Fornecedor")
public class Fornecedor {

@OneToMany (mappedBy="fornecedor", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
List<Produto> produtos;
```

Classe ProdutoBean método Remover

```
public void RemoverProduto(Produto p) {

    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("venda_estoque");
    EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
    manager.getTransaction().begin();

    ProdutoRepository pr = new ProdutoRepository(manager);
    Produto produto = pr.Remover(p.getId());
    manager.remove(produto);

    manager.getTransaction().commit();
    manager.close();
    factory.close();
}
```

Comment: Você poderia adicionar a parte do código que faz a remoção desses registros?

Comment: coloquei o código remover, pensei que seria algo com mapeamento

Comment: Esse é o mesmo caso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141690/removendo-itens-de-uma-rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o-onetomany-por-omiss%C3%A3o

Comment: mas no caso só a classe produto que puxa o id do fornecedor, já a classe fornecedor não possui id nem lista que use

Comment: editei as classes fornecedor e produto fazando o mapeamento mas não está funcionando

Answer (score 0):

Seguinte, você pode ter tido um mesmo problema que eu. Para o método de remoção do JPA junto com a EntityManager, deve-se mesclar o objeto sempre quando fizer o find, assim:

```
private final static EntityManager manager = ConnectionFactory.getEntityManager();

public T findById2(Class<T> clazz, Long id) {
    manager.getTransaction().begin();
    return manager.find(clazz, id);
}

public void remove(T t) {
    manager.merge(t);
    manager.remove(t);
    manager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```